# Как получить значение ячейки со смещением в google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Как получить значение ячейки относительно его позиции, а не прописанное самостоятельно? (Аналогично `ActiveCell.Offset.Value` из VBA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аналог в GAS - это метод Range - [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer))

Пример использования (взято оттуда же):

```
function testOffset(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");

  // newCell references B2
  var newCell = cell.offset(1, 1);
}
```

P.S. Если нужно получить значение ячейки - то воспользуйтесь методами объекта Range:

1. [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())
2. [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
3. [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue())
4. [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues())

Comment: А если это пользовательская функция и мне нужно, чтобы смещение было относительно ячейки, в которой она записана? При том, что я заранее не знаю, в какую ячейку она будет записана( вернее место записи - динамическое)

Comment: Эта функция - и есть смещение относительно другой ячейки.

Comment: Это я понял, я и спрашиваю, что если мне нужно смещение не относительно известной ячейки, а относительно ячейки, в которую записана пользовательская функция, при том, что она заранее неизвестна.

Comment: Текущую ячейку можно получить с помощью [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange()) либо [getActiveCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveCell())

Comment: Благодарю. Вы очень помогли.

Comment: @age-of-creations ваша ошибка в том, что вы сравниваете VBA и Google Apps Script. Не делайте этого, т.к. сравнивать там нечего. Пользовательская функуция не знает позиции, где она запущена. Ей необходимо передавать эти параметры.

Comment: Поправка. Пользовательская функция думает, что она находится в активном диапазоне, поэтому можно `var tergetRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow() + 1`